# Mapping (x,y) co-ordinates to bits in a byte array - as quickly and efficiently as possible

Tags: c#, embedded, bit-manipulation, .net-micro-framework, lcd

I'm using C# ([.NET Micro Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/netmf/default.aspx) running on the [Netduino Plus](http://www.netduino.com/netduinoplus/specs.htm)) to control an LCD screen of 84 x 48 pixels.

Each pixel in the LCD screen has two states: `1` (ON) or `0` (OFF). To control the pixels in the screen, I need to send an array of `504 bytes`, where each `byte` represents one column of 8 pixels (ie, the screen is 'split' into 6 rows of 84 x 8 pixels).

This is best demonstrated with an example:

- The byte `00000001` (`2^0`) represents one column of eight pixels, where the first pixel at the top of the column is ON (`1`).
- The byte `00001001` (`2^0 + 2^3`) represents another column of eight pixels, where the first and 4th pixels from the top of the column are ON.

From this you can see that a bitwise `AND` operation will show which pixels in a given column are ON or OFF. For example, to see if the 4th pixel in a given column of 8 pixels is ON:

```
00001001    AND
00001000
-----------------
00001000 > 0
∴ The 4th pixel is ON
```

The problem is that I need to be able to use `(x,y)` co-ordinates to access each pixel in the screen. For example, the point `(3,10)` would represent the pixel 4 to the right of and 11 below the pixel in the top left corner of the screen. Similarly, the point `(83,47)` would represent the bottom right pixel of the screen.

I have written the following C# code to achieve this:

```cs
byte[] display = new byte[504];

// storing these means they don't need to be calculated every time:
byte[] base2 = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };

// Determine if the pixel is ON (true) or OFF (false)
public bool PixelState(Pixel px)
{
    return (display[GetColumn(px)] & base2[GetPxNum(px)]) > 0;
}

// Find the number of the pixel in its column of 8
private int GetPxNum(Pixel px)
{
    return px.y % 8;
}

// Find the index of the byte containing the bit representing the state of a pixel
private int GetColumn(Pixel px)
{
    return (px.y / 8 * 84) + px.x;
}

// Set a pixel's state
public void SetPixel(Pixel px, bool state)
{
    int col = GetColumn(px);
    int num = GetPxNum(px);

    if (state && !PixelState(px))
        display[col] += base2[num];
    else if (!state && PixelState(px))
        display[col] -= base2[num];
}

// Represents one (x,y) point
public struct Pixel
{
    public int x, y;

    public Pixel(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Since this is running on a microcontroller, I need the code to be as quick and efficient as possible. This is also necessary because these methods may be called many times in quick succession to update pixels in the LCD screen.

Therefore my question is **how can I make this code faster and more efficient? Is there any better way of going about this?**

**EDIT:** After some extensive testing I've realised that I should be using `Math.Floor` (or just an integer operation) in `GetColumn`. I've updated my code.

Comment: How are you using C# in a microcontroller? Or is it just a proof of concept? Also: which microcontroller? This question depends A LOT on the available instruction set.

Comment: Of course, I should've included that information in the question. It's the Netduino Plus: http://www.netduino.com/netduinoplus/specs.htm, which uses the Atmel AT91SAM7X512 microcontroller.

Comment: Then you're pretty much constrained by your framework optimization. These kind of frameworks tend to suck so the way to make it faster and more efficent is... drop .NET and stick to pure ASM or at least a lower level language, like C (Atmel's C is pretty cool, you should be using it!) BTW, do you really need to make it more efficent? It doesn't seem like this would be a bottleneck so you might be a victim of premature optimization.

Comment: BTW, I think you're overcomplicating this. If you have `px.x` and `px.y`... do you really need the `GetColumn` and so?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left out the `Pixel` struct from the question (added it now). `px.x` and `px.y` are the `(x,y)` point. `GetColumn` and such are required to locate the byte in the array containing the bit representing the pixel with the given co-ordinate.

Comment: Would have given you a few C tidbits to speed things up but then... .Net?! Why?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to using .NETMF because I need to use the Netduino Plus. I need the performance benefits of it's integrated ethernet controller and micro SD card reader (these features will be necessary later if I continue with my project).

Comment: BTW, you can use Netduino Plus with pure ASM (just forget using the IDE and upload the data yourself.) The ethernet controller and micro SD reader must be accessible from C too (although you might need to twist your code to access it, but it performance is critical...)

Comment: Woops, I forgot you were writing to bits, that's why I couldn't make sense of your code :P

Comment: `GetPxNum` uses the `y` co-ordinate to work out which BIT in the BYTE (8 bits in a byte, remember) represents the pixel. For example, given the point `(8,31)`, `GetPxNum` will determine that the bit representing the pixel will be the 8th pixel in the column (`31 mod 8 = 7`, zero would represent the 1st bit in the column of 8 pixels).

Comment: BTW, taking a closer look at *netduino* it looks like a great piece of hardware. A bit expensive (compared to Raspberry PI, which I'm looking forward to) but it looks awesome anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little snippet in `SetPixel`:

```
if (state && !PixelState(px))
    display[col] += base2[num];
else if (!state && PixelState(px))
    display[col] -= base2[num];
```

Could be replaced by:

```
if (state)
    display[col] |= base2[num];
else
    display[col] &= (byte)~base2[num]; // You could precompute this inverse array too
```

If you've got plenty of memory available precomputing might be okay but, seriously, uCs have SO MUCH processing power these days. Are you really going to notice a little bit-shift or negation?

---

Also, you might be interested in not using `(double)` and `Math.ceiling()` since your microcontroller probably has no floating point support, so it must be emulated (with a consequent drop of performance. Using `(float)` would make it better (single precision emulation is faster) but even better would be this:

```
return ( (px.y/8 + ((px.y%8)?1:0)) * 84 ) + px.x;
```

**EDIT:** taking a closer look at netduino it *might* have a FPU (although I can't see it in the datasheet, so it probably doesn't...) The integer math alternative is probably still faster :)

---

Wether it's faster can only be assured by testing but, like I said in the comments, this is arguably going to be a bottleneck and you look just like another victim of premature optimization.

The biggest bottleneck here is your framework.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean `(px.y % 8 > 0) ? 1 : 0)`? Your code gives a type conversion error.

Comment: Don't worry anyhow - I've just realised that I should be taking the floor instead of the ceiling in `GetColumn`. I've updated the question and submitted an edit for your answer. :)